# AZURE SYNAPSE ANALYTICS - HOW TO RELATE TABLES?

Tags: azure, cloud, dimensional-modeling, azure-synapse

I'm new to Azure synapse analytics and I'm trying to crate internal tables to create my DW.

I have just found out that we cannot use primary key/foreign key.

My question is, how do I relate my fact tables with my dimension tables? is it necessary to create any kind of relationship between them or just create it plainly and use joins whenever needed?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating your tables with the [primary key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-table-constraints#examples) identified, it helps the optimiser make better query plan choices.

There is currently no syntax supported for foreign key identification.

As you suggested, just go ahead and write your joins.